# Android M Permission denied after it was granted

Tags: android, file-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm getting this error after the permission was allowed and the activity was recreated.

```
I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
     W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
     W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9e23f960, error=EGL_SUCCESS
     W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
     W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
     W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1004)
```

and

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:452)
```

The code for asking for permission is:

```
     if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
     }
```

After the crash when I start the app I do not see the permission dialog and everything works fine, I can open the Camera with intent.
I'm using Emulator. Nexus 5 API 23.

Comment: This error is not related to Android permissions. It seems to be a file system related issue `java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`.

Comment: Possible, but next time I try it is working fine after permission is granted.

Comment: It's a well known bug. The permissions WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are granted only after the app is closed and opened again.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in Android M.  Might be only on the emulator though.

This is a [link](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2982) to the issue on google dev forums.
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2982

The owner says:

> Since the issue exists still in emulator 6.0, reopening the issue  But
>   working fine on MRA58K devices

I'm still seeing this on the emulator as well.

Comment: This bug still exists in 2019, on an android 10 emulator

Answer (score 1):

If you add the CAMERA permission to your manifest, but the user hasn’t granted it at runtime, you will notice that the external intent to capture a photo will fail and throw a SecurityException.

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/e9kyM7VXajz